# Null reference exception when connecting to a database

Tags: c#, sql-server

When I call the `UserExists` method via the `DataBaseService` class instance it fails immediately to connect to database. Instance is null despite the fact that I have provided the `SqlConnection` with a connection string.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Somename
{
    public class DataBaseService
    {
        // Setting up the Database Services
        private SqlConnection myConnection;
        private const string ConnectionString = "Data Source=Test-LAPTOP\\MSSQLSERVER1;Initial Catalog=myDatabaseTest;Integrated Security=True";

        private static readonly DataBaseService _instance;

        static DataBaseService()
        {
            _instance = new DataBaseService();
            Initilize();
        }

        public static DataBaseService Instance;
        private static void Initilize()
        {
            try
            {
                Instance.myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                Instance.myConnection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error while connecting to DB: " + ex.Message);
                return;
            }
        }

        public bool UserExists(string username)
        {
            var myQuery = "Select * from UserProfile where userId ="+username+"";
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(myQuery, Instance.myConnection);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            //sqlCmd.CommandText = "Select * from Customers";
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

            DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
            sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);

            if (dtRecord == null)
            {
                return false;

            }  
            else 
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you never assigned `Instance`, which would explain why it's null..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Providing a connection string does not create a connection instance.

Answer (score 1):

You have two instances of `DataBaseService` in your code, `_instance` and `Instance`. You initialize `_instance` in the static constructor, but never initialize `Instance`.

You probably want to use `_instance` everywhere you're currently using `Instance`, and get rid of `Instance` entirely:

```
...

private static readonly DataBaseService _instance;

static DataBaseService()
{
    _instance = new DataBaseService();
    Initilize();
}

private static void Initilize()
{
    try
    {
        _instance.myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        _instance.myConnection.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error while connecting to DB: " + ex.Message);
        return;
    }
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to follow this pattern:

```
private static DataBaseService _instance;
// public property
public static DataBaseService Instance
{
    get
    {
        return _instance ?? (_instance = new DataBaseService());
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be a great answer if it had some explanation about why the OP's code is failing and then suggestion the pattern.

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't address the question asked at all

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11818362)

Comment: @RoadieRich Yes it does.